# Gojs resizable group

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a one group in my diagram, which contains nodes and links.
How to make my group always 100% diagram's width and 100% diagem's height?

How to achive that? Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Set the **Diagram.autoScale** property to `go.Diagram.Uniform`.

```
  $(go.Diagram, . . .,
    {
      autoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
      . . .
    })
```